# Structuring RSpec file structure and code for tests with very large coverage?

Tags: namespaces, metaprogramming, rspec, taxonomy

I've just started looking at a project that has >20k unit tests written in Rspec (the project itself isn't written in Ruby; just the test cases).  The current number of test cases is expected to grow dramatically in the future, as more functionality is added.  What's already happened (over an extended period) is that RSpec started out being a particularly good solution for testing this project, but as the project has grown, the fairly ad-hoc structure of their RSpec test cases has bitten them badly.  One of the biggest problems they've got is with taxonomy in their test code - the structure (or lack of) in naming their test cases, fixtures, helper code etc. in their test cases.

As you could imagine, with >20k unit tests, there's a lot of methods with very similar names, using helper methods that are all loaded from a global namespace.

To highlight just one area where the problem is biting, there's ~10 databases within this application.  Checking the structure of tables/columns/views/constraints/stored procs/... for all of these databases is something that (quite reasonably) is covered within the existing RSpec unit tests.  However, the total number of DDL entities within this collection of databases that needs to be checked is probably >10000; covering the whole range of DB structural checks *and* being able to selectively test only subsets of DB structure requires either:

- > 10000 separate methods (and I'm ruling out that option straight away!)
- a fairly complex naming convention within the test cases (i.e. something encompassing the DB name + table name + column name + ...),
- OR passing e.g. DB name, table name, column name, ... to a generic method
- OR separation of concerns via namespaces (and I'm not aware of an elegantly scalable way of doing this within RSpec),
- OR some clever metaprogramming (that I suspect could ultimately make an already messy structure even more difficult to follow).

What exists now is a bit of all of the above, as far as I can tell, with not a lot of obvious planning...

Do you have any tips or references I could look at to try to straighten out this mess, and give them some sort of scalable structure to their RSpec testing?  In particular, suggestions on how to structure the various RSpec files for very large projects would be very welcome.

Comment: Why can't you generate a lot of the DB checks directly from the DDL for the databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The RSpec Book](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/achbd/the-rspec-book) is an excellent resource for RSpec tips and tricks, and for BDD methodology in general (although your focus appears to be more about testing). There are several ways to simplify and DRY up specs to make them easier to manage, including shared examples (Chapter 12) and macros (Chapter 17).

I also recommend [David Chelimsky's blog](http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/).

Still it looks like your project could be a real challenge. Of the approaches you mentioned, I think using macros with DB, table, and column as parameters is the most promising.

Comment: I've gone through the RSpec book (well, my version's a couple behind the current one...), but found nothing at all relating to how to structure code for extremely large test bases.  The book has examples that are easy enough to understand, but they're also pretty trivial; what I'm after is advice on how to scale up to deal with very large numbers of tests, and I can't see any coverage of that in the book at all.

Comment: Fair enough. Do check out Chelimsky's blog, or drop him an email if you're so inclined. SO is pretty sparse on RSpec as of yet.

RSpec itself is tested with RSpec, so that's always a good source of inspiration: http://github.com/rspec/rspec-core

Comment: Thanks for your response, zetetic.  I think the unpleasant reality is that there's no existing body of work describing how people have recovered from situations like this, and there's no 'cleverness' inherent in Rspec that makes it easy to do - it's simply a slow grind to get it sorted out.

I can see a discussion about the merits of building a new test suite  simply to test the existing test suite, and to provide support in refactoring it, is going to emerge at some point.  Hopefully the universe doesn't explode with that level of recursion.

Comment: Ha! That's if the LHC doesn't find the Higgs boson and create a black hole first, of course.

You're right though, it looks like you'd be blazing a trail by scaling up to the size you envision. If you do come up with a solution, please post it here.